# Remove string from stringbuilder when deselected from listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a Listview, it is Multiselect and when i select one item, the string will be added in a Stringbuilder My problem is when i deselect the item..i want it to be removed in the Stringbuilder..please help :( thank you

my code:

```
 myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) myList.getItemAtPosition
                    (position);
            String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_NAME));




            s.append(title);

           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            //shopName.setText(content);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not directly add into the StringBuilder on list item select.

Create an `ArrayList<String>`, and dynamically add / modify / remove.

If you are concerned on the position, you can use a `Map<String,String>` instead.

Then use a function to build the entire string from the `ArrayList<String>` or `Map<String, String>`.

It is a much more cleaner approach for me.